# Trying to build an example from DJI PSDK (ERROR: Please confirm your platform.)

Tags: linux, dji-sdk, manifold

I'm trying to follow the DJI's documentation of the PayloadSDK to understand better the workflow. But when I type the line " cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. ", on (https://developer.dji.com/document/c685f35c-5033-42ee-9dcc-e242ef19fd98), the build stops and shows an ERROR:

CMake Error at CmakeList.txt:32 (message):
FATAL: Please confirm your platform.

Please could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This error pops up when your system is neither x86_64 nor aarch64. Are you using a raspberry Pi? Cause you might have Armv7, which is aarch32.

if (USE_SYSTEM_ARCH MATCHES LINUX)
add_definitions(-DSYSTEM_ARCH_LINUX)
add_subdirectory(samples/sample_c/platform/linux/manifold2)
add_subdirectory(samples/sample_c++/platform/linux/manifold2)

```
execute_process(COMMAND uname -m OUTPUT_VARIABLE DEVICE_SYSTEM_ID)
if (DEVICE_SYSTEM_ID MATCHES x86_64)
    set(LIBRARY_PATH psdk_lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc)
elseif (DEVICE_SYSTEM_ID MATCHES aarch64)
    set(LIBRARY_PATH psdk_lib/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "FATAL: Please confirm your platform.")
endif ()
```

This is the code sequent i'm reffering to. You can view the whole thing here:

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Payload-SDK/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt